# Page content distort when resized to small size

Tags: css

I've placed a wide background image at : [site page](http://www.utilitiesindia.com/bank-account-details-payment). Now when I resize the browser by reducing the width, the right sidebar mixes with the beautiful background.

What I want is that, the overlapped portion of the bg image to be hidden and the sidebar to be positioned over that portion whenever the size is reduced so that it does not look all mixed up on smaller screens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sidebar could use a solid background, so

`div#sidebar-right{background:white;}`

**EDIT**

You can also add the style inline, which only affects the homepage:

`<div id="sidebar-right" class="sidebar" style="background:white;">`

Comment: It's a drupal site, I don't want to tinker the core code. Any other idea?

Comment: See my edit above @AgA.  Just add that to the homepage and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes it worked. I'm curious why! Also can you please tell me whether it's going to affect any other pages in the site?

Comment: @AgA, before you added the code, the `div` was transparent, so it looked like the picture from the center was overlapping.  This style change just made the background a solid color, so the picture cannot "show through".  If you added the code to the CSS file, it will make every right sidebar on the site with that `id` have a solid white background, but that should be fine.  Check it, though. If it messes up another page, remove the style from the CSS and add it just to the homepage, as I showed in the second example.

Comment: Thanks. Is it due to because the z-index of the bg-image is lower than the sidebar? So the non-transparent white bg of sidebar will be on the top of the image when resized?

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't your image HTML?
You could just apply `max-width:100%;` to it.

Comment: What do you mean? Put the bg image in <img?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a `background-color: white;` in the CSS on your `.sidebar`. It has to be adjusted a little bit, but it will solve your initial problem.

The concern here is that the sidebar actually doesn't have a background...

Comment: Thanks, can you please see my comments above?

Comment: ? You don't have to "tinker the core code". If you are not able to apply any CSS at all, this will be a difficult task. What are your options and tools for editing something? You don't tell in you question. Right now there are no code problems with what happens - you just have no bagground on the sidebar, så you will always be able to see what's behind it. You have to set a background or put a larger margin, so the sidebar will never end over anything else.

Comment: Yours is correct solution, thanks! I've edited the css file, sorry for confusion.

Comment: You are as correct as Jason, I could have equally selected your answer as well :)